# Realm update based on condition in Swift

Tags: swift, realm

I have an object that I only wish to update if the stored timestamp is less than the timestamp in the updated data. In mysql I would set a condition like `UPDATE items SET email="admin@google.com" WHERE timestamp < 1725239737` What is the best way to do this in realm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. Fetch all objects, then update the email value:

```
// Query all objects with Item Realm Object Class
let datetime = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1725239737)
let items = realm.objects(Item.self).filter("timestamp < %@", datetime)

// Write to Realm
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    for item in items {       
        item.email = "admin@google.com"
    }
}
```

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#filtering